# In how many ways can you order in line the letters of the word $AAABBCDEFG$

Tags: combinatorics

In how many ways can you order in line the letters of the word $AAABBCDEFG$ , such that $A$ or $E$ will be the first letter?
I'm thinking there are $2$ options for the first letter ($E$ or $A$) and $9!$ options for the rest, and then I want to divide by $3!\cdot 2!$ (because there are 3 A's the 2 B's), so: $$\frac{2\cdot9!}{3!\cdot2!} = \frac{9!}{3!}$$
But... I'm not sure because when I tried it for smaller versions it didn't give the correct answer. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

No, you are not correct.

First fix $A$ in the first place. The other 9 letters can be arranged in $\frac{9!}{2!2!}=90720$

Now, fix $E$. The other 9 letters can be arranged in $\frac{9!}{3!2!}=30240$

Then, the total ways is $90720+30240=120960$

Answer (score 1):

There are two cases to deal with - starting with $A$ and starting with $E$.

If we start with $A$, then there are $9!$ combinations, divided by $2!$ rearrangements of the $2$ remaining $A$'s and $2!$ for the $2$ rearrangements of the $B$'s. If we start with $E$, then there are $9!$ combinations, divided by $3!$ rearrangements of the $3$ $A$'s and $2!$ for the $2$ $B$'s. The total number of possibilities is:
\begin{align*}
\frac{9!}{2!2!} + \frac{9!}{2!3!} &= \frac{9!}{4} + \frac{9!}{12} \\
&= \frac{9!}{3} \\
&= 120960
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

Let's count all words starting an $E$: $$\frac{9!}{2!3!}$$
And all the words starting with an $A$ : $$\frac{9!}{2!2!}$$
So the final result is : $$\frac{9!}{3}$$